# Iterate over IMapView using WRL

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

I need to iterate over IMapView which I get from `Windows::ApplicationModel::Store::LicenseInformation`. It should work with standard `for_each`, bud I cannot use C++/CX, only WRL.

All I have now is `ComPtr<IMapView<HSTRING, ProductLicense*>> productLicences;` How can I get content of *productLicences* to some standard collection?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem on a different MS platform, and came across this unanswered question. It may be too late, but this is how I solved it.
The key is that IMapView inherits from IIterable, so you need to get the IIterable interface (using QueryInterface) and get an Iterator. The following code is an adaptation from my platform to yours so it may not be 100% correct, but it provides the key elements to do the iteration using WRL.

First, obtain the IIterable interface and a valid Iterator.

```
ComPtr<IMapView<IKeyValuePair<HSTRING,ProductLicense*>> map;
THROW_IF_FAILED(licenseInfo->get_ProductLicenses(&map));
unsigned int mapSize = 0;
THROW_IF_FAILED(map->get_Size(&mapSize));
wprintf(L"map size %i\n", mapSize);
ComPtr<IIterable<IKeyValuePair<HSTRING,ProductLicense*>*>> iterable;
panelMap.As(&iterable);
ComPtr<IIterator<IKeyValuePair<HSTRING,ProductLicense*>*>> iterator;
```

Now you have all the info you need to do the iteration. Set the iterator to the first element of the Map and start iterating. The code below illustrates the iteration process.

```
THROW_IF_FAILED(iterable->First(&iterator));
boolean hasCurrent = false;
THROW_IF_FAILED(iterator->get_HasCurrent(&hasCurrent));

while(hasCurrent)
{
    ComPtr<IKeyValuePair<HSTRING,ProductLicense*>> pair;
    THROW_IF_FAILED(iterator->get_Current(&pair));
    HString key;
    THROW_IF_FAILED(pair->get_Key(&key));
    ComPtr<IProductLicense> license;
    THROW_IF_FAILED(pair->get_Value(&license));
    THROW_IF_FAILED(iterator->MoveNext(&hasCurrent));
}
```

This should work fine in most windows platforms that support WRL, with minor reaming of some methods (e.g. in my platform iterator->Current(..) had a slightly different name).